# How to add layouts to tab fragments?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, layout, tabs

I'm trying to create an Android up that has a Tab layout achieved using ViewPager. 
I can't understand where i have to handle the layout of any tab.
I know there's the function `onCreateView()` in the `PageFragment` class that does that and i already done this:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);

        switch(mPage)
        {
            case 1:
                ScheduleList(view);
                return view;
            case 2:
                // Do something.
                return view;
            case 3:
                // Do something.
                return view;
        }
        return view;
    }

    public void ScheduleList(View v) {
        ItemsLst = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listview);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Items);
        ItemsLst.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

This simply shows a `ListView` in the first Tab. This action is handled in the `switch` inside the `onCreateView()` method. 
Here is the XML layout for the `ListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The issue is that i can have only the `ListView` in the XML file so i can't manage other `case:` in the switch for showing other UI elements.

For example, the first tab shows the `ListView`and i want to show some text in the second Tab and some other in the third. 
How can i do it?
Thank you in advance, hope i explained myself.

Comment: Crate 3 different fragments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have already handled the layout file :/, you are supposed to give a layout file for each fragment.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
```

the code above sets the fragment layout to res/layout/fragment_page.xml

if you are still a bit confused, I would recommend following this tutorial :D - http://www.exoguru.com/android/material-design/navigation/android-sliding-tabs-with-material-design.html

Comment: I got it! My project structure is a little bit different than the project inside the link you gave me but i solved the issue. Thank you very much!

Comment: I like the tutorial. Google has the sample working code for SlidingTabs as well.